# Understanding messages in my console

Tags: pdftex, tikz-cd

After I installed tikzcd, I got this message in my console window after typesetting.

> ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]

I would like to understand what does the line beginning with ADB mean, and also why the next line is appearing ? (I am using pdftex & LaTeX, and I do not have any error)

Comment: It's just an innocuous information message. I agree that it's annoying and should only appear in the log file, not in the console output.

Comment: And do you know why the next line appears ? What is an MPS to PDF converter ? Is it because of some format of tikzcd ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First message (package `everyshi`)

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

This comes from package [`everyshi`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/everyshi). `ABD` means the place of execution and is short for `\AtBeginDocument`. It's an information or even only a debug message. I agree with egreg, see his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246055/understanding-messages-in-my-console#comment585017_246055), that this should be rather only appear in the `.log` file.

## Second message (MetaPost support)

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
```

Usually this file `supp-pdf.mkii` is loaded by [`pdftex.def`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdftex-def), the driver file for packages `graphics` and `color` to support pdfTeX.
The program MetaPost generates PostScript files, which uses a quite limited subset of the language PostScript. Therefore it is possible with reasonable effort to support this kind of PostScript for use as graphics files in pdfTeX. This work was done by Hans Hagen for his ConTeXt. `pdftex.def` loads this module to convert/import MetaPost PostScript files  (`MPS`) for use with LaTeX package `graphics`. The notice in the message could only go into the `.log` file, but ConTeXt might have other conventions about this.

If you do not want to load this support, it can be disabled by providing `\convertMPtoPDF`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand*{\convertMPtoPDF}[3]{%
  \errmessage{MPS files are not supported by choice}%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really really nice and clear answer !